# How do I deserialize a Doctrine object with JMSSerializerBundle?

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-odm

I am using Doctrine-ODM and I'm trying to (de)serialize document Objects in Symfony.

The serialization seems to work, but when I try to deserialize I get the following error:

> You must define a type for My\Bundle\Repository\Item::$id.

I try to deserialize with this call:

```
$object = $serializer->deserialize($serializedItem, 'My\Bundle\Repository\Item', 'json');
```

My document has a few Embedded Documents but they seem to be okay in the serialized String. It is missing Information about the Document-Type. Here a simplified example of the output:

```
{
    id: "itemID",
    - embededDocument: {
        id: "embeddedDocumentID",
        moreInformation: true
    }
}
```

now I have read the [usage instructions](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle/master/usage) and I assume that my solution is explained [in the metadata for third party cookbook](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle/master/cookbook/metadata_for_third_party), but I can't figure out what to do.

How do I fix that and deserialize my Strings to Objects properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `My\Bundle\Repository\Item`, you need to define an `id` property, and decorate it with [the @Type annotation](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle/master/reference/annotations#type).

Comment: thanks a lot :) we decided to go another way but this helped a lot back then :)